# innerHTML text quickly disappears after being applied to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an HTML/CSS/JS pre-scripted shell session to demonstrate some examples of different commands, like a demonstration shell. My issue is once the 2nd `innerHTML +=` is applied it appears on the screen and immediately disappears. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this behavior. In my mind, it seems like it should be added to the node and left there but something is resetting it and I don't know what.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="shell"></div>

  <script src="shell.js"></script>
</body>
```

**The JS:**

```
var data = "python success.py ";
var shellUser = '<span class=\"name\">dev@bash: ~ $ </span>';
var output = "success!";
var i = 0, text;

(function shell() {
  text = data.slice(0, ++i);

  document.getElementById('shell').innerHTML = shellUser + text;

  if (i == data.length) {
    document.getElementById('shell').innerHTML += '<br />' + output;
  }

  setTimeout(shell, 150);

}());
```

**The CSS:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

#shell {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      width: 80%;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 0.5rem
  }
  .name {
      color: #ff00e4;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 0.6rem;
  }
```

**Here it is in action:**
https://jsfiddle.net/L0qvomeb/

What am I missing here that could be causing the `var output` to disappear after being rendered to the DOM? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you keep calling `shell()`, and when `i > data.length`, it will no longer show the `output`

A simple fix would be to do this:
https://jsfiddle.net/L0qvomeb/1/

```
if (i == data.length) {
    document.getElementById('shell').innerHTML += '<br />' + output;
} else {
      setTimeout(shell, 150);
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the smallest things are the hardest to figure out when you've been staring at the code for a while. Thanks for your help, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Change `i == data.length` to `i >= data.length`

Comment: Although this would work, there is no point to keep processing to show the same data.